# Symbolic Linking On WinXP

Tags: windows-xp, cygwin, symbolic-link

I'm running Windows XP and Cygwin.  Is there a way to create some kind of symbolic link so that, if a non-Cygwin program is passed /cygdrive/c as a command line argument, it looks in c:\ for whatever file/directory it needs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to create symbolic links on Windows, download the [Junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) tool from Microsoft and use it to create a symbolic link (On NTFS they are implemented as junction points).  And then create a \cygdrive\c directory and create a junction point form it to c:\

```
md \cygdrive\c
junction \cygdrive\c \
```

Now this may or may not work, I don't have cygwin installed.  It relies on:

1. Programs interpreting the forward slashes in /cygdrive/c as backslashes (which some may do)
2. Having your working directory set to the drive with the symlinks since paths starting with \ are relative to the current drive.

Comment: Obviously not a perfect solution for the reasons you mentioned, but definitely good enough for my needs.

Comment: Junctions are not the same as symlinks (which only appeared in Vista).

Comment: But they're good enough.  I have this solution up and running.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling cygwin-unaware programs from cygwin's bash and passing paths as arguments like

```
$ windowsProgram.exe "pathArg1" "pathArg2"
```

then maybe convert every pathArg into "$(cygpath -w pathArg)" i.e. say

```
$ windowsProgram.exe "$(cygpath -w pathArg1)" "$(cygpath -w pathArg2)"
```

. Ugly, but should work?